# Calculate route in road network

Tags: pgrouting

I have a shapefile of road network. I have found out the nodes on the network.

I want to calculate all the possible routes from a start point to the end point. I am using PostgreSQL, PostGIS and pgRouting.

Comment: Are you aware that there are an almost endless number of routes between 2 points? Depending upon how different you want routes to be.

Answer (score 0):

You probably start with the [pgRouting workshop](http://workshop.pgrouting.org/) to get familiar with how pgRouting works.

When you understand how it works, then you may want to try out "[pgr_ksp - K-Shortest Path](http://docs.pgrouting.org/2.0/en/src/ksp/doc/index.html#ksp)", which returns not only the "shortest" but also alternative routes.